# hide/disable <div> and <a> onlick of and image but restore them when it backs to original status

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

Please see the live example: http://jsfiddle.net/greedylan/ftmg4kbs/

Is there a way to turn off the `div.mask` and `<p>resistor</p>` after clicking the thumbnail? I don't need the mask and title bar when the it shows the bigger image. But I do them to be restored when we click the `.close` link to close the enlarge picture. I have tried to use CSS selectors as follow but they don't work.

```
.boxes li#one:target + div.mask {display:none}
.boxes li#one:target ~ a {display:none} 

.boxes li#one:target ~ p {display:none}
```

do we need javascript in this case? 
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*changed*/
li:not(:target) .view:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(150px);
}
```

The :not(selector) selector matches every element that is NOT the specified element/selector.

```
/*added*/
li:target .view .mask {
    display:none;
}
```

------> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ftmg4kbs/2/)